# Load different youtube videos by ID at the end of a quiz depending on the outcome

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, switch-statement

I'm nearly done!

For those of you playing at home I've been trying to build a vanilla javascript quiz for a uni project. I've had a stack of help from the awesome people of stackoverflow. Hopefully this is the last question :)

Fiddle of everything: https://jsfiddle.net/funkefiddle/tsnr8hra/

I have a multi question quiz. Results are tallied in an object. At the end of the quiz when the 'results' div is display == block a function will work out the final answer and edit the innerHTML.

I would like to play one of four different Youtube videos depending on the final answer result.

My JS:

```
        if (document.getElementById("results").style.display == "block") { // Check that we are on the 'results' stage of the quiz, ie the final page. 
            return loadYTPlayer();  

             if (finalResults == "Ninja") {
             player.loadVideoById(d2iD_j1MrJc); 
             console.log('Ninja: d2iD_j1MrJc')
             }
             else if (finalResults == "Robot") {
             player.loadVideoById(B1BdQcJ2ZYY);
             console.log('Robot: B1BdQcJ2ZYY')
             }
             else if (finalResults == "Pirate") {
             player.loadVideoById(TzMbGPa-Vus);
             console.log('Pirate: TzMbGPa-Vus')
             }
             else if (finalResults == "Zombies") {
             player.loadVideoById(TzMbGPa-Vus);
             console.log('ZombiePirates? TzMbGPa-Vus') // Zombies are lame. Moar pirates pls!
             }
          }
        }

function finalResults() {   // Get the values of the answerData object to work out which result is the highest. We need to compare the results somehow.

    var theAnswer = Object.keys(answerData).reduce(function(a, b){ return answerData[a].score > answerData[b].score ? a : b });
    return theAnswer;
}

// Now for a prize for all those loyal quiz participants.
function loadYTPlayer() {

      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
     }


      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: '',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

     function onPlayerReady(event) {
       event.target.playVideo();
    }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {

          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
```

I know i'm not calling on the function loadYTPlayer() properly, however if I don't put it in a function the video starts to play immediately upon the page load (despite the div being hidden).

I understand that I can use player.loadVideoById(vidID) to start the video playing a custom video i'm just not sure when to call this in relation to the loadYTPlayer() function so that the video isn't playing the entire time the user is completing the quiz.

Please halp.

Edit: I modified the code to reflect both the suggestions below. Changed the if evaluation to not look at whether a div display is none or block. Also changed the chained IFs to a switch. 
I'm not getting a console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadVideoById' of undefined"

```
if (nextQuestion == "results") { // If the nextQuestion is equal to results (the ID of the final div) we are at the end of the quiz and need to do a bunch of stuff
        document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById("finalResulthere").innerHTML = "<p>You are a " + finalResults() + ", congratulations!</p><p>Now kick back and enjoy your prize.</p>"; // Modify the innerHTML to display the output of the finalResults function. This should display a paragraph telling us what our personality is.

        loadYTPlayer(); // We have to load the YouTube iFrame API


        var videoId = '';
        switch (finalResults) { // Find the correct video file to load by comparing the finalResults output to the available names in this switch statement. If one of them matches, assign the correct videoId to the variable of the same name. 
        case "Ninja":
            videoId = "d2iD_j1MrJc";
            console.log('Ninja: d2iD_j1MrJc');
            break;

        case "Robot":
            videoId = "4YJ3BTKMILw";
            console.log('Robot: 4YJ3BTKMILw');
            break;

        case "Pirate":
            videoId = "TzMbGPa-Vus";
            console.log('Pirate: TzMbGPa-Vus');
            break;

        case "Zombies":
            videoId = "TzMbGPa-Vus";
            console.log('ZombiePirates? TzMbGPa-Vus'); /* Zombies are lame. Moar pirates pls! */
            break;
        }

        player.loadVideoById(videoId); // Start playing the video that matches the final personality type. 

    } else { // If the nextQuestion is not 'results' just display the next question in sequence. 

        document.getElementById(nextQuestion).style.display = "block"
    }
```

Comment: It's not good at all to track a state depending on an element's visibility... You should use variables instead.

Comment: I had no idea. But i can imagine. Okay so i've added a var to keep track of the current question div id. Then modified the IF to check if the currnetQuestion var is 'results' 

var currentQuestion = this.parentElement.id; // Get the current div's ID to keep track of where we are
 console.log("Current element ID is: " + currentQuestion);

if (currentQuestion == "results")

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
 // Check that we are on the 'results' stage of the quiz, ie the final page. 
 if (document.getElementById("results").style.display == "block") {
   /* removed return from here as we want to execute code after this statement also. */
   loadYTPlayer();  

   var videoId = '';
   switch (finalResults) {
     case "Ninja":
       videoId = "d2iD_j1MrJc"; 
       console.log('Ninja: d2iD_j1MrJc')
       break;
     case "Robot":
       videoId = "B1BdQcJ2ZYY";
       console.log('Robot: B1BdQcJ2ZYY');
       break;  

     case "Pirate":
       videoId = "TzMbGPa-Vus";
       console.log('Pirate: TzMbGPa-Vus');
       break;

     case "Zombies":
       videoId = "TzMbGPa-Vus";
       console.log('ZombiePirates? TzMbGPa-Vus'); /* Zombies are lame. Moar pirates pls! */
       break;
   }
   player.loadVideoById(videoId);
 }
 }
```

> After `return` statement function control is transferred from where function invoked;

Wrap non numeric values in double quotes `"non numeric value here"`;

Comment: For some reason I decided it would be a good idea to play with the if statement to make the entire last div load. And to remove the IF off a style.display. And now the video isn't loading at all... again. 

Updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/funkefiddle/tsnr8hra/2/

Comment: For this to work you need to load youtube api before using it as it takes time to load and init api; so you can load it on page load;

Comment: If i change the function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() to include a videoId it will start playing the video in the background after the first 'start the quiz' button press - then when it reaches the very final page it will stop playing it and reload the iframe without a videoId.

Comment: From the current code it looks like the code inside `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` is not triggered after api load; may you conform that this is executing after api load;

Comment: Yes the video iframe itself is loading but is displaying "An error occurd. Please try again later". My current assumption is that the videoId we're assigning in the switch isn't reaching onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() . The console is showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadVideoById' of undefined
And i've just noticed the console.log in the switch isn't logging anything to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a string instead:

```
player.loadVideoById("d2iD_j1MrJc");
```